# How to use http-proxy-middleware with express router in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, express-router, http-proxy-middleware

I am trying to use http-proxy-middleware in NodeJs. It is not working. I am working on node version 18.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const app = express();

const PORT = 6001;
const HOST = "localhost";    //tried with 127.0.0.1 also
const API_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
   
const proxyOptions = {
    target: API_URL,
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {
        [`^/api/posts/all`]: '',
    },
}

router.get('/all',createProxyMiddleware(proxyOptions));

app.listen(PORT, HOST, () => {
    console.log(`Proxy Started at ${HOST}:${PORT}`)
});
```

I am trying endpoint **http://localhost:6001/api/posts/all** and getting this issue **Cannot GET /api/posts/all**

Answer (score 0):

The API for listing all posts is `/posts`, not `/posts/all`.

An working example

```js
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const app = express();

const PORT = 6001;
const HOST = "localhost";
const API_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";

const proxyOptions = {
  target: API_URL,
  changeOrigin: true,
  pathRewrite: {
    [`^/api`]: '',
  },
}

app.use(createProxyMiddleware(proxyOptions));

app.listen(PORT, HOST, () => {
  console.log(`Proxy Started at ${HOST}:${PORT}`)
});
```

When access the `http://localhost:6001/api/posts` endpoint, the logs:

```bash
[HPM] Proxy created: /  -> https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
[HPM] Proxy rewrite rule created: "^/api" ~> ""
```